# Why wont my display update with my background? The window just opens black. Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to learn OOP but my pygame window wont update with the background I'm trying to put in. The gameObject class is in another file. Filling it with white color also isn't working and I don't know why. I was able to display a background on another project I did but I cant now and I have no idea what's different. I have compared the code and they seem like they should be doing the same thing.

gameObject.py

```
import pygame 

class GameObject:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_path):
        self.background= pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (width, height))

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
```

main.py

```
import pygame
from gameObject import GameObject

pygame.init()

class Player(GameObject):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_path, speed):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, image_path)

        self.speed = speed 

    def move(self, direction, max_height):
        if (self.y >= max_height - self.height and direction > 0) or (self.y <= 0 and direction < 0):
            return

        self.y += (direction * self.speed)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 800
        self.color = (255, 255, 255)

        self.game_window = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.background = GameObject(0, 0, self.width, self.height, 'assets/background.png')

        self.player1 = Player(375, 700, 50, 50, 'assets/player.png', 10) 

        self.level = 1.0

        
    def draw_objects(self):
        self.game_window.fill(self.white_color) 

        self.game_window.blit(self.background.image, (self.background.x, self.background.y))

        pygame.display.update()
    
    def run_game_loop(self):

        gameRunning = True
        while gameRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameRunning = False
                if gameRunning == False:
                    pygame.quit()
    
        self.draw_objects()
        
    
        self.clock.tick(60)

game = Game()

game.run_game_loop()

quit()
```

I have tried basic research on it and looking at other code that uses a custom background with pygame

Comment: `self.game_window.blit(self.background.image, (self.background.x, self.background.y))` afaict there is no `GameObject.image` in the code sample you posted, so this code should just crash.

I assume you also meant to call `self.draw_objects()` in the loop and `self.clock.tick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of indentation. `self.draw_objects()` must be called in the application loop not after the application loop:

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def run_game_loop(self):

        gameRunning = True
        while gameRunning:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameRunning = False
                if gameRunning == False:
                    pygame.quit()

        # INDENTATION
        #-->|
    
            self.draw_objects()
            self.clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop never actually does anything but clear the event queue looking for pygame.QUIT.

You need to indent the calls to self.draw_objects() and self.clock.tick(60) so they are inside the loop.